# Can someone help provide proper configuration to have protractor run in firefox, and compatible version of firefox

Tags: firefox

I am using the following configuration for protractor :

```
"protractor": "^5.4.2",
"should": "^7.1.1",
"webdriver-manager": "^12.1.1",
"webpack": "^1.12.6"
[11:06:02] I/status - selenium standalone version available: 3.141.59 [last]
[11:06:02] I/status - chromedriver versions available: 2.45, 2.46 [last]
[11:06:02] I/status - geckodriver versions available: v0.13.0, v0.17.0 [last], v0.21.0, v0.24.0
[11:06:02] I/status - android-sdk is not present
[11:06:02] I/status - appium is not present
config file 
capabilities: {
browserName: 'firefox',
marionette: false,
firefoxOptions: {
args: ['--headless']
},
'moz:firefoxOptions': {
args: ['--headless']
}
}
```

firefox version currently is 56.0.2. Because i wanted to run headless and i read that it is only supported in 55+, but the tests wont run with this set up:

```
[09:15:39] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[09:15:39] I/hosted - Using the selenium server at http://localhost:4444/wd/hub
[09:16:24] E/launcher - Timed out waiting 45 seconds for Firefox to start.
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:53'
[10:58:36] E/launcher - WebDriverError: Timed out waiting 45 seconds for Firefox to start.
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
at Object.checkLegacyResponse (/home/Development/lrp-protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/error.js:546:15)
at parseHttpResponse (/home/Development/lrp-protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:509:13)
at doSend.then.response (/home/Development/lrp-protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:441:30)
at process.internalTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:77:7)
From: Task: WebDriver.createSession()
at Function.createSession (/home/Development/lrp-protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js:769:24)
at Function.createSession (/home/Development/lrp-protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/firefox/index.js:521:41)
at createDriver (/home/Development/lrp-protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/index.js:170:33)
at Builder.build (/home/Development/lrp-protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/index.js:632:16)
at Hosted.getNewDriver (/home/Development/lrp-protractor/node_modules/protractor/built/driverProviders/driverProvider.js:53:33)
at Runner.createBrowser (/home/Development/lrp-protractor/node_modules/protractor/built/runner.js:195:43)
at q.then.then (/home/Development/lrp-protractor/node_modules/protractor/built/runner.js:339:29)
at _fulfilled (/home/Development/lrp-protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:834:54)
at /home/Development/lrp-protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:863:30
at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/home/Development/lrp-protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:796:13
```

Can run the test in chrome however without any issues. I tried older version of firefox (47) it works and runs the test but fails because it is not full screen and i tried running in headless, but still opens up the browser.

I am fairly new to set up and configuration. Great if someone could provide info.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this as suggested on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47770336/protractor-invalid-ssl-certificate: add `acceptInsecureCerts: true` to `protractor.conf.js` block `capabilities`.

If this doesn't help, you may be able to debug the problem by adding line

```
console.log("parsed:", parsed);
```

To `/home/Development/lrp-protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js` before line 509 or thereabout.